# Filepicker UI loading issue

Tags: filepicker.io

Sometimes, the Filepicker.io UI fails to load in an iframe giving an error:

Error: Load timeout for modules: main
    require.min.js:32
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

Kindly suggest a solution to this issue, how it should be handled by the host app.

Comment: Hi there. Filepicker here. It looks like a javascript file that we use is not being loaded. We're serving those js files out of cloudfront and have a backup on cloudflare to avoid these problems so it's a bit surprising. Looking into why that might be the case.

Comment: We have increased the timeout, so you should no longer be seeing these issues